# Using cElementTree to parse attributes

Tags: python, xml, parsing, celementtree

I am learning cElementTree and my XML looks like this.... I am trying to obtain the "updated" text ( which I can! ) and the attribute value of "href" in the "link" node ( which I can't ).

```
<feed>
    <entry>
        <link href="http://www.mondocars.com/0001127602.htm"/>
        <updated>2017-04-19T13:10:24-04:00</updated>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

My code to parse it looks like this...

```
for entry in root.findall('entry'):
    updated = entry.find('updated').text
    print updated
    for link in root.findall('link'):
        href = link.get('href').attrib
        print updated, href
```

href value isn't being pulled at all. I am convinced that it's probably an unnecessary 2nd for loop. updated populates fine but I can't figure out how to get the href value. Anyone encounter this?

Many thanks in advance.
Janie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for entry in root.findall('entry'):         
    updated = entry.find('updated').text
    href = entry.find('link').attrib.get('href')
    print updated,href
```

is the correct way.